# Reduce code - duplicated code appending svg images

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have an svg graph with several different types of nodes, with each type having many different nodes with a different purpose.

Products,
Communities,
Events,
Projects,
Product-Groups.

I want to set the background images of each node.

Each individual node of each of these groups, has its own unique ID.
The type and ID of these nodes can be used to retrieve the image from an endpoint for all of the types except for the product-groups whose images are in an assets folder.

I am trying to call images from 1. endpoints and 2. from an assets folder.

My endpoints represent the different types and have the IDs parsed in:

```
https://tiktok.org/products/${node.id}/standard

https://tiktok.org/communities/${node.id}/standard
```

My current method of doing this seems EXTREMELY inefficient, and i'm not supposed to have duplicated code! I 'append' an svg image and an ID, then i reference these for the node.types and parse their ID but this is just shedloads of code (heres two types as an example):

```
   .selectAll('circle.node')
    .data(this.nodes)
    .enter();
  //products
  circle
    .filter(node => node.type === EngagementType.Product)
    .append("pattern")
    .attr("id", d => `insightImage-${d.id}`)
    .attr("patternContentUnits", "objectBoundingBox")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", d => `https://tiktok.org/products/${d.id}/standard`) (fake link)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 1)
    .attr("height", 1)
    .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid slice');
  //communities
  circle
    .filter(node => node.type === EngagementType.Community)
    .append("pattern")
    .attr("id", d => `insightImageCom-${d.id}`)
    .attr("patternContentUnits", "objectBoundingBox")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", d => `https://tiktok.org/communities/${d.id}/standard`)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 1)
    .attr("height", 1)
    .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid slice');
```

Then I fill the circle with the style attribute like below:

```
  circle
    .filter(node => node.depth !== 0 && node.type === EngagementType.Product)
    .append('circle')
    .classed('Engagement-GraphNode', true)
    .classed('Engagement-GraphNodeBackground', true)
    .classed('Engagement-GraphLeaf', node => node && (node.depth === 4 && !node.isExtraNode))
    .style('fill', d => `url(#insightImage-${d.id})`)
    .style('opacity', node => (node.visible) ? 1 : 0)
    .style('visibility', node => (node.visible) ? 'visible' : 'hidden')
    .on('click', node => onClick(node));
  circle
    .filter(node => node.depth !== 0 && node.type === EngagementType.Community)
    .append('circle')
    .classed('Engagement-GraphNode', true)
    .classed('Engagement-GraphNodeBackground', true)
    .classed('Engagement-GraphLeaf', node => node && (node.depth === 4 && !node.isExtraNode))
    .style('fill', d => `url(#insightImageCom-${d.id})`)
    .style('opacity', node => (node.visible) ? 1 : 0)
    .style('visibility', node => (node.visible) ? 'visible' : 'hidden')
    .on('click', node => onClick(node));
```

I have a similar method for the images in the assets folder, i have a bunch of images.svg and then do the same as above for the product group but actually call them individually taking up MASSES of space...

in this instance i call on the nodes via their ID to assign individually the image from tha assets folder:

```
      circle
    .filter(node => node.type === EngagementType.ProductGroup && node.id === 'a6qb000000003olAAA')
    .append("pattern")
    .attr("id", `insightImageInitiative`)
    .attr("patternContentUnits", "objectBoundingBox")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", './assets/d3-icons/initiative.svg')
    .attr("x", 0.2)
    .attr("y", 0.2)
    .attr("width", 0.60)
    .attr("height", 0.60)
    .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid slice');
  circle
    .filter(node => node.type === EngagementType.ProductGroup && node.id === 'a6qb000000003okAAA')
    .append("pattern")
    .attr("id", `insightImageIndustry`)
    .attr("patternContentUnits", "objectBoundingBox")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", './assets/d3-icons/industry.svg')
    .attr("x", 0.2)
    .attr("y", 0.2)
    .attr("width", 0.60)
    .attr("height", 0.60)
    .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid slice');
```

I tried simply just using style (fill) but it wouldnt work for me!!

```
    .style('fill', d => `url('./assets/d3-icons/calendar.svg')`) 
    .style('fill', d => `url('https://tiktok.org/products/${d.id}/standard')`)
```

nothing appears!

Some advice / help on either how to differently set the images OR how to get rid of so much duplication would be amazing!

Im sure there is an easier way to set the background images, of course the endpoints are different though.

thanks if you can help!

Comment: use `node.type` **inside** the callbacks

Comment: How? I don't see any callbacks sorry

Comment: callbacks === arrow functions

Answer (score 1):

The data object you use can be anything. The most appropriate pattern is to prepare it before you attach it to the elements selection, and in such a way that you have everything you need already on hand.

The following example defines a data structure mapping from types to the data that differ per category. This is only an example, the core is what happens in the `.map()` function: you add one or more properties to your data object so that you have the connection between `node.type` and the way you need to write your pattern just right for every node.

A similar way to connect from ids to the asset folder images will be needed.

It is a bit strange that you define a pattern for each node, but only draw a circle if `node.depth !== 0` But that is for you to understand, use the filter function only to identify the non-toplevel entries that need a circle rendered.

```
const details = new Map([
    [EngagementType.Product, { path: 'products', prefix: 'insightImage'} ],
    [EngagementType.Community, { path: 'comunities', prefix: 'insightImageCom'} ],
    // and so on...
]);

// enhance your data, each node is a shallow copy with extra properties
const renderingData = this.nodes.map(node => Object.assign({
    patternId: `${details.get(node.type).prefix}-${d.id}`,
    imageUrl: `https://tiktok.org/${details.get(node.type).path}/${d.id}/standard`,
    isLeaf: node.depth === 4 && !node.isExtraNode
}, node));

const circle = d3.selectAll('circle.node')
    .data(renderingData)
    .enter();

// now it is straight forward
circle
    .append("pattern")
    .attr("id", d => node.patternId)
    .attr("patternContentUnits", "objectBoundingBox")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0);
    .append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", d => d.imageUrl)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 1)
    .attr("height", 1)
    .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid slice')
  // and now you filter for non-toplevel nodes
  .filter(node => node.depth !== 0)
    .append('circle')
    .classed('Engagement-GraphNode', true)
    .classed('Engagement-GraphNodeBackground', true)
    .classed('Engagement-GraphLeaf', node => node.isLeaf)
    .style('fill', d => `url(#${d.patternId})`)
    .style('opacity', node => (node.visible) ? 1 : 0)
    .style('visibility', node => (node.visible) ? 'visible' : 'hidden')
    .on('click', node => onClick(node));
```

Comment: I have just seen this, I will go through it and try to use it soon, thank you.